# Content Place Holder is being cached on ASP Web Forms, while using Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, caching, webforms

I am writing an ASP Web Forms application and have problem with what seems to be a client cache. But first few details about application.
Application is using ASP Forms Authentication with following configuration in the web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
```

There are 2 aspx pages that I want to talk about, Default.aspx and Login.aspx. Both pages are using the same master page Site.Master. This master page is displaying info about user, like Hello Mr Smith, and name of current the page like Home.
Besides that this application is being hosted on the server farm with 4 servers. Session is being kept with "sticky session", a cookie is being added to the client's browser with specific server ip for load balancer.

Now when I go to the default page, I am being redirected to the Login page, which is correct. Then I successfully log in and I am redirected to the default page - the url in browser changes, page reloads.

**The problem** is that, when I go to the default page after logging in, master page is being refresh - info about user is being filled, and the title changes to Home, but the content of master page's Content Place Folder remains that of the Login page. So I have url for home page in the browser, master page for logged in default.aspx but still content of login.aspx. Here is the screenshot of the situation:
http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/1020/azvz.png

Only the Default page still has the Login page content displayed, all other pages in application are displaying correct content, even though they are using the same master page.

Refreshing the Default page does not help.
Clearing all browser data, like cache does not help.
This issue happens **only sometimes**. I can't find a pattern with which it occurs. Once it happens on a browser it stays that way for a week or two.
Using different user in the browser, like incognito session, does help.
It happens on different browsers - tested on IE 10, FF 25 and Chrome 31.
It happens only on production, so only on server's farm. It never happened on dev environments like localhost.

At first I thought that the login page is being cached on client side (browser) but for some reason it is not being clear with clearing the browser's cache. So I tried disabling the client-side cache on both default and login pages with this:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

But it didn't help.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: Can you a) restart your app pool, b) go to the browser and open the network trace (F12 in IE/Chrome and go to the Network tab, ensure 'preserve log on navigation' is set) and then - c) repeat the process of logging in and see what responses you're getting from the server. Tell me what you find or better still post another image to imageshack - I think this is a forms auth issue and may be to do with your web farm configuration, but a network trace will help.

Comment: Can you post the ASPX content of your MasterPage?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for comments and sorry for my late response.
@sh1rts,
a) Restarting app pool did not help. The whole server is being restarted from time to time because of the updates, but still it does not resolve problem.

b,c) I am getting the response from the server with wrong page already in it's content. The screenshots are here:
After login:

http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/3408/39fu.png

After ctrl+r:

http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/5913/w4nj.png

If wrong elements are shown in the screenshots, please let me know, and I will update the screens.

Comment: @dgarbacz,
Here are snippets:
Master Page:
http://snipt.org/Bvhd9/Default
Login Page:
http://snipt.org/Bvhe8
Default Page:
http://snipt.org/Bvhf2